# Viewing the body of the sys defined packages

Tags: sql

Can we view the actual content of the packages defined in sys..?

Answer (score 0):

To me, "SYS" looks like "Oracle" - if it is not, specify which database you use.

Anyway: for **Oracle**, the answer is "yes", at least for some packages (such as `STANDARD`). Connect as a privileged user (the one who can query `DBA_SOURCE`).

For example, this will return the `USER` function's code:

```
SQL> select * from dba_source
  2  where name = 'STANDARD'
  3    and type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
  4    and line between 177 and 182
  5  order by line;

OWNER NAME     TYPE               LINE TEXT
----- -------- ------------ ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
SYS   STANDARD PACKAGE BODY        177   function USER return varchar2 is
SYS   STANDARD PACKAGE BODY        178   c varchar2(255);
SYS   STANDARD PACKAGE BODY        179   begin
SYS   STANDARD PACKAGE BODY        180         select user into c from sys.dual;
SYS   STANDARD PACKAGE BODY        181         return c;
SYS   STANDARD PACKAGE BODY        182   end;

6 rows selected.
```

This is how we use it:

```
SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
MYDBA

SQL>
```

On the other hand, some code is *wrapped* so you'll see *garbage*, e.g.

```
SQL> select * from dba_source
  2  where name = 'DBMS_PICKLER'
  3  order by line;

OWNER NAME     TYPE               LINE TEXT
----- -------- ------------ ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
SYS   DBMS_PIC PACKAGE BODY          1 package body dbms_pickler wrapped
      KLER                             a000000
                                       1
                                       abcd
<snip>
                                       abcd
                                       abcd
                                       b
                                       b59 3b5
                                       m6CkwovE0yvcssGORq1xtBLOvMkwg1UrDNDrfC+Lg+QYOK47iYQ+jchNM48U
                                       3OA7hqJKA36u
                                       9w7KqGfDVuSq1GQhoQOUJmfKwMLBCNeG/dAJ985KkY5RZTFq7s2cxjPOCFWw
                                       crud+wrWynmi
                                       2FQ+yozlLgyTLz1gLuwJvdkhPmt+jlqbyUTx5WCe43XKwJplaxFA3+c1LI6N
                                       rKVnyKwV1/Mt
                                       JHa8GTaU9xZnTHk34EBXqH3HNRxXlGmABVCGBkKUuG+hogcUxfxh4AiksMLp
```